# How to change Haskell code formatting rules in VS Code

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm using VS Code with the Haskell extension v2.2.1 and the Haskell Syntax Highlighting extension v3.6.0.

When I write:

```hs
data Name = Name
  { first :: String
  , last :: String }
```

And I invoke formats election on it I end up with

```
data Name = Name
  { first :: String,
    last :: String
  }
```

How can I change this behaviour, so that it keeps the first way of formatting (with leading commas)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default formatter for the Haskell extension is `ormolu` which always uses trailing commas.

In the VSCode settings for the Haskell extension you can choose a different formatter. For example `fourmolu` which is a fork of `ormolu` with more configuration options. [It has a setting for the comma style](https://github.com/fourmolu/fourmolu#available-options):

> `comma-style` |   **`leading`**, `trailing` | Where to place commas in lists, tuples, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. 

Surprisingly I didn't have to install `fourmolu`! -- And even more surprisingly it is not on my path (which includes ~/.ghcup/bin)